# Join dataframe with spatial object and get its spatial boundaries - R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial-join

I am trying to do Spatial + Non-Spatial object join here. However, I am trying to get the spatial coordinates of the matching ids. I tried to use `sp::merge`, but that is doing the other way around.

My dataframe has ids, I am trying to get the spatial boundaries of those ids alone from spatial polygons data frame.

df looks like,

```
id 
1
2
3
2
1
```

spatialpolygondf will also have a column called id in its attributes. How can I join them together to get the boundaries ?

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example using sample data?

Comment: give a try to library(sf), then the standard dplyr verbs may be used; if you use library(sp) you should fortify your spatialobject

Answer (score 2):

From what I'm gathering, it looks a combination of the **sf** and **dplyr** packages might work.

```
#load files:
spatial <- st_read("C:/filepath/filename") 
nonspatial<- read.csv("C:/filepath/filename")

#use inner_join:
df1 <- inner_join(spatial, nonspatial, by = "ID")
```

This should return all the rows from your spatial object, where there are matching values in the non-spatial object and all the columns from both.

You can use st_boundary() with mutate(), to create a new boundary column for the IDs. Then, use select function() in dplyr to create a smaller dataframe with your ID and spatial boundaries columns.

```
#data for analysis:
df1%>%
  mutate(df1, boundaries_ col = st_boundary(ID))
  select(ID, boundaries_col)
```